# Exception on incompatible types when defining inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: php, oop

I've defined a DTO class and then, another one that extends from the first.

```
namespace App\DTO;

class DTO {};

namespace App\Modules\Auth\User\DTO;

class DTO extends App\DTO\DTO {

...Some definitions here

}
```

Next I created a generic repository interface;

```
namespace App\Interfaces;

interface iRepository {

   public function create(App\DTO\DTO $data);

}
```

And finally, a class repository for my User Model;

```
namespace App\Modules\Auth\Repository;   

class UserRepository implements App\Interfaces\iRepository {

   public function create(App\Modules\Auth\DTO\SignUpDTO $data) {

      ...some code here
   }
}
```

I'm getting an error about incompatible type in function create.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Declaration of App\Modules\Auth\Repository\UserRepository::create(App\Modules\Auth\DTO\SignUpDTO $data) must be compatible with App\Interfaces\RepositoryInterface::create(App\DTO\DTO $object)

I thought polymorphism means that I could use both App\DTO\DTO and App\Modules\Auth\DTO\SignUpDTO since the second inherits the first.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I got to resolve this problem by changing the "create" method's signature and setting as argument a DTO class. Like this:

```
namespace App\Modules\Auth\Repository;   

class UserRepository implements App\Interfaces\iRepository {

   public function create(App\DTO\DTO $data) {

      ...some code here
   }
}
```

This way I can call the create method using a SignUpDTO as argument.